# Is $(x,y) \mapsto (\frac xy, x^2-y^3)$ an automorphism of $k(x,y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. The group of automorphisms of $k(x,y)$ is the [cremona group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253481/finding-all-automorphisms-of-mathbbcx-y); see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group).

If we are given a map $H: k(x,y) \to k(x,y)$, defined by 
$H(x):= f \in k(x,y)$ and $H(y):=g \in k(x,y)$ and extended to all $k(x,y)$ in a way that makes it a $k$-endomorphism of $k(x,y)$,
is there a criterion which tells if $H$ is an automorphism of $k(x,y)$? Probably in general it would be very difficult, so special cases are also of interest.

In particular,

> Is $H: (x,y) \mapsto (\frac xy, x^2-y^3)$ an automorphism of $k(x,y)$?

Define $\tilde{H}: k^2 \to k^2$ by $\tilde{H}(a,b) \mapsto (f(a,b),g(a,b))$.
Then for $t \in k^{\times}$: $\tilde{H}(t^3,t^2)=(\frac{t^3}{t^2}, (t^3)^2-(t^2)^3)=(t,0)$; perhaps this may help, I am not sure.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: I am feeling very dense.  What do you mean by $(x,y)\mapsto(f,g)$ - aren't these elements of $k(x,y)$?  Do you mean $x\mapsto f$ and $y\mapsto g$?  But then what does $H(t^3,t^2)$ mean?

Comment: An automorphism of $k(x,y)$ should have one variable only, that is an element of $k(x,y)$. What you mean, I guess, is the map $R(x,y)\mapsto R(f, g)$ where $R(x,y)$ is an arbitrary element of k(x,y) (?).

Comment: @JasonDeVito, thank you. Yes, I meant $x \mapsto f \in k(x,y)$ and $y \mapsto g \in k(x,y)$. $H(t^3,t^2)$ means $H$ on the curve $x=t^3,y=t^2$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, thank you. Yes, I meant that $H: k(x,y) \to k(x,y)$  is defined by $H(x):=f \in k(x,y)$ and $H(y):=g \in k(x,y)$ and extended to all $k(x,y)$, which is what you have suggested.

Comment: It is not. Here is a hint. $[k(x,y):k(\frac{x}{y}, x^2-y^3)]=3$, not 1.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that if $[k(x,y):k(\frac xy, x^2-y^3)] > 1$ then $k(\frac xy, x^2-y^3) \subsetneq k(x,y)$ and so $H$ is not onto. But why is the degree of that field extension three?

Comment: That the field extension degree is three is not immediately obvious to me. We are certainly dealing with a finite separable extension, so it should be that the big field is generated over the little by a single element. I will search.

Comment: Here’s what I found: Putting $s=x/y$ and $t=x^2-y^3$, I’ll find a cubic for $x$ over $k[s,t]$: we have $x^2-t=y^3$, and $s^3=x^3/y^3=x^3/(x^2-t)$, so that $F=X^3-s^3X^2+s^3t$ is the minimal polynomial for $x$ over $k[s,t]$. I’m confident that $F$ is irreducible in $k[s,t,X]$ — indeed a Newton Polygon argument verifies this.

Comment: Write $u=\frac{x}{y}, v=u^2-y$. Then $k(x,y)=k(u,y)=k(u,v)$. Then, $k(\frac{x}{y},x^2-y^3)=k(u, y^2(u^2-y))=k(u, (u^2-v)^2v)$. The last one is a polynomial of degree 3 in $v$ and the rest should be clear.

Comment: Good, @Mohan! I think your argument is quite different from mine.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you!

Comment: Great argument,  @Mohan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the images of $x$ and $y$ are independent transcendentals in $k(x,y)$, your map is well-defined as a field morphism, and therefore one-to-one. But you need to check that the image is all of the codomain, i.e. that the map is onto. In other words, you need to express $x$ as a rational function of $x/y$ and $x^2-y^3$, similarly for $y$.
It’s not clear what “$f(t^2,t^3)$” can mean, till you tell me what element of $k(x,y)$ is equal to $t$.

**EDIT- expansion**:

It seems clear to me from your comments and from what I complained about above that you don’t fully apprehend the definition of your map $H$.

This is the way that $H$ is defined, using the given recipe $H(x)=x/y$, $H(y)=x^2-y^3$. It means that for a general rational function $\rho(x,y)$, described in the upper line of the display below, $H(\rho)$ is as described in the second line.
\begin{align}
\rho&=\frac{\sum_{i,\,j}a_{ij}x^iy\,^j}{\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}x^iy\,^j}\\
H(\rho)&=\frac{\sum_{i,\,j}a_{ij}(x/y)^i(x^2-y^3)\,^j}{\sum_{i,\,j}b_{ij}(x/y)^i(x^2-y^3)\,^j}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to show that $x$ or $y$ or any other element of $k(x,y)$ is not a rational function in $\frac xy$ and $x^2-y^3$? (perhaps the way that Mohan suggests is the easiest one; I do not know if there are other ways).

Comment: Writing $y=u(f,g)/v(f,g)$, $u,v \in k[x,y]$ and then taking $x=0$ yields: $y=u(0,-y^3)/v(0,-y^3) \in k(y^3)$ is a contradiction, so it is impossible to write $y$ as a rational function of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I’ll explain what’s illicit about “take $x=0$ in an edit to my post.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the problem is when $v(0,-y^3)=0$? (though I do not think there is a problem with that).

Comment: You may not evaluate $x$ and $y$ here, unless to a pair that make up a transcendence base for the field $k(x,y)$

Comment: Dear Lubin, if I understand correctly you are not claiming anything about  the surjectivity of the map $H$, right?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, in this answer and its comments, I do not make any such claim. In the comments to OP’s question, however, two of us agree that the field extension degree is three.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.